# Deriving a class instance for a type based on another class it's an instance of

Tags: haskell, type-families, deriving, derivingvia

I have a situation where I have some similar `newtypes` that all need to be instances of `Random`, `Arbitrary`, and lots of other stuff. They all need the *same* custom implementation of the functions `randomR`, `random`, `arbitrary`, etc. So I put all of those implementations in a class.

Here's a simplified example, that just handles `Random`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstrainedClassMethods #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies            #-}

import qualified System.Random as SR

-- Numbers that are restricted to a narrower range
class Narrow t where
  type BaseType t

  -- Unsafe constructor for the instance type
  bless :: BaseType t -> t

  -- Safe constructor for the instance type
  narrow :: (Ord t, Bounded t) => BaseType t -> t
  narrow x | x' < (minBound :: t) = error "too small"
           | x' > (maxBound :: t) = error "too big"
           | otherwise     = x'
    where x' = bless x :: t

  -- Deconstructor for the instance type
  wide :: t -> BaseType t

  -- Random
  randomR
    :: (Ord t, Bounded t, SR.Random (BaseType t), SR.RandomGen g)
    => (t, t) -> g -> (t, g)
  randomR (a, b) g = (narrow x, g')
    where (x, g') = SR.randomR (wide a, wide b) g

  random
    :: (Ord t, Bounded t, SR.Random t, SR.RandomGen g)
    => g -> (t, g)
  random = SR.randomR (minBound, maxBound)
```

Here's a example of one of the types that I want.

```
-- | A number on the unit interval
newtype UIDouble = UIDouble Double
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

instance Bounded UIDouble where
  minBound = UIDouble 0
  maxBound = UIDouble 1

instance Narrow UIDouble where
  type BaseType UIDouble = Double
  bless = UIDouble
  wide (UIDouble x) = x
```

I want this to be an instance of `Random`. Ideally I'd like to write something like:

```
deriving ?strategy? instance SR.Random UIDouble
```

and have the compiler know to use the methods defined in `Narrow` to implement `Random`. But instead I have to write

```
instance SR.Random UIDouble where
  randomR = randomR
  random = random
```

It's not a problem doing this for a few methods, but doing this for `Num`, `Fractional`, `RealFrac`, `Floating`, `Serialize`, etc. for each of my types is a bit tedious.

An alternative I've explored is to write

```
instance (Narrow t) => SR.Random t where
  randomR = randomR
  random = random
```

because I'd only have to write this once for the class, rather than repeat it for each type. But that leads to `UndecidableInstances` which I understand are bad. I could do this with `TemplateHaskell`, I'm sure. **But I wonder if there is some fancy language pragma or type-level programming magic that will streamline this?**

Comment: "` UndecidableInstances` which I understand are bad" -- this is a common misconception. There is a risk you'll make the compiler loop, if your definitions are circular. (Yours aren't.) Providing the compiler does finish, the object code is type-safe and happy. (If running it loops, that's not because of `UndecidableInstances`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you define a newtype and give it the instance you want once and for all:

```
newtype UseNarrow a = UN a
instance Narrow a => SR.Random (UseNarrow a) where
    randomR (UN lo, UN hi) g = (UN v, g) where v = randomR (lo, hi) g
    random g = (UN v, g) where v = random g
```

Then in all of the places where you want to use that instance, you write:

```
deriving via (UseNarrow UIDouble) instance SR.Random UIDouble
```

I may have some of the syntax a tad off, as I didn't test the above. But you should have the idea.

For further reading, look for `DerivingVia` in the GHC User Manual.

Comment: I thought that `DerivingVia` required specifying a type that `UIDouble` would be coerced to. So wouldn't the `minBound` and `maxBound` end up being that of the coerced type?

Comment: @mhwombat I... don't think so? Note that the `randomR` on the RHS of the method definition in the instance I'm showing here is being called at type `a`, not `UseNarrow a`! (In fact, the instance context doesn't even demand enough constraints to guarantee the *existence* of a `minBound`/`maxBound` for type `UseNarrow a`.)

Comment: @mhwombat You're talking about the via type which is `UseNarrow UIDouble`. Daniel used standalone deriving but you can also write it traditionally: `newtype UIDouble .. deriving SR.Random via UseNarrow UIDouble`.

Comment: You can think of the `SR.Random (UseNarrow UIDouble)` dictionary being coerced into the `SR.Random UIDouble` dictionary

Comment: @Iceland_jack Well, I used standalone deriving because the question used standalone deriving...